# expression evaluation confusion in c++

Tags: expression

Can somebody please explain to me what is going on here?

I have this line of code:

```
if ( pt->child == NULL && pt->visits < cutoff+1 || depth > 5 )
```

and I'm getting a *g++ compiler* warning:

```
warning: suggest parentheses around ‘&&’ within ‘||’ [-Wparentheses]|
```

What is it trying to warn me of? And worse, if I put in the "obvious" parens, like so:

```
if ( ( pt->child == NULL && pt->visits < cutoff+1 ) || depth > 5 )
```

I get a different behavior -- indicating I really did do something wrong in the first expression. Arithmetic operators have higher precedence over comparisons which have higher precedence over boolean operators where `&&` has higher precedence than `||`, right?

What am I missing?

Comment: Well, if the "obvious" parens were not the ones you intended, what **did** you intend?

Comment: What was the behavior before, and how did it change?

Comment: The obvious ones are what I meant, but the program behaves differently with and without those parens. I can't see why. It is part of a much bigger program so there is no easy answer to comment #2.

Comment: Your warning message contains smart/curly quotes `‘&&’` and in `‘||’` --- if that is part of your code, that will surely cause an error. Replace with standard quotes `'&&'` and in `'||'`

Comment: My code is as seen 2 lines above the warning message.

Comment: Then why does the generated error message contain smart/curly quotes?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point

Comment: I cut and pasted the warning message. It shows as italic, so when I paste I think it's just an artifact. My code has no quotes. The warning is trying to show where I should be paying attention.

Comment: The GNU documentation says that the warning message is there to remind you that the && operator has higher precedence than the ||. The really strange thing is that the second line of code behaves differently as it shouldn't. Could you explain in what exact way the program behaves differently?

Comment: Not really.  :)  It is a game playing program and that line is buried deep in the move generation code. The move actually found differs depending on which of the two versions (shown above) are used. I went back and forth a few times to confirm it was not a fluke. That documentation you quote sure sounds like it's not trying to say anything besides the obvious then....

Comment: Re sequence points, I don't see any place in that "if" where there would be any side effects.

Comment: Hmm, I can't see how the parentheses would make any difference in this case. Tried all types of examples, but I may have a different compiler. You might need to test this method / function in isolation to the rest of your program to see exactly what is happening.

Comment: Agreed. I just assumed there was something I was not understanding. I need to pull it out and really see what's going on. Thank you everybody for your comments, thoughts, and suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Just like the numeric operators + and *, the logical operators have different precedence.  So the order of evaluation of a logical statement will not necessarily be strictly left to right, but will instead evaluate && first and || 2nd.  This has been the source of so much confusion and error that the compiler will emit this warning unless you explicitly surround the elements with parentheses.

What going on here?  I think in this case it's erroneous because if you make g++ dump it's internal structures

this

```
if ( pt->child == NULL && pt->visits < cutoff+1 || depth > 5 )
   printf("Hello World");
```

equates to this

```
D.3367 = pt->child;
if (D.3367 == 0B) goto <D.3368>; else goto <D.3364>;
<D.3368>:
D.3369 = pt->visits;
D.3370 = cutoff + 1;
if (D.3369 < D.3370) goto <D.3365>; else goto <D.3364>;
<D.3364>:
if (depth > 5) goto <D.3365>; else goto <D.3366>;
<D.3365>:
printf ("Hello World");
<D.3366>:
```

Which does exactly what you would expect.